# Why am I only able to run installed npm packages via npm run?

Tags: node.js, less, package.json

I have installed the less compiler (`lessc`) and stylelint (`stylelint`).

I don't wish these to be installed globally, so they are in `package.json`'s dev dependencies section. I am only able to run them via `npm run <some name here>`. I'd like to be able to manually run them via simply typing `lessc` as though it was globally installed.

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "stylelint ./src/**/*.less",
    "compile": "lessc --help"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "less": "^2.7.3",
    "stylelint": "^8.3.1"
}
```

Having to tweak the `compile` npm script everytime is not ideal, which is why I'd like the option of experimenting from the command line.

I tried `npm lessc --my-flags-here` but this is not a valid command. Is what I'd like to do possible, or will I have to stick to editing package.json every time?

Comment: If they're installed locally (as opposed to globally), then they won't be on your PATH.  You can probably do something like `node_modules/.bin/lessc`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed them locally they aren't available globally, so in order to access them with using `npm run` you'd need to reference the folder in which they are contained in the current project's directory.

Something like this would work: `node_modules/.bin/lessc`